# OpenID is not working. How to map the previous account to the new account

Tags: support, stack-overflow, openid

I had openId and I logged into Stack Overflow with the login, but OpenID was shut down and I'm not able to login with the openid, so I have created a new user account. Is it possible to map my old user account with this newly created account?

Answer (score 2):

You can contact the Stack Exchange team and get the accounts merged. The process is documented [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts), but essentially, just hit [Contact Us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) at the bottom of any page when you're logged in, and you can choose the option for merging accounts. They'll confirm ownership, then do some magical things to get them merged together.